# Nhibernate Session closed exception issue with Asp.net mvc telerik ajax grid

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, nhibernate, telerik

I am getting Nhibernate Session closed exception with asp.net mvc telerik ajax grid. The grid is bound to an entity Sale that has a related entity User. The exception thrown is when trying to access the User entity. I have used the fetchMode to eager load it but I still get the same exception. This exception only occur if I switch between the grid pages multiple times. Anyone encountered this issue?

The code for that data access is as follow:

```
public IList<Sale> List()
        {
            var manager = new ManagerFactory().GetSaleManager();
            var iCriteria = manager.Session.GetISession().CreateCriteria(typeof(Sale))
                .SetFetchMode("AspnetUser3.Agents3", FetchMode.Eager);

            return iCriteria.List<Sale>();
        }
```

The code that try to access the related object in the object graph is as follow:

```
AgentId = sale.AspnetUser3.Agents3[0].Id,
```

The exception thrown

```
NHibernate.Exceptions.GenericADOException: could not load an entity: [SalesEntry.Data.Model.AspnetUser#7aaabf99-d77d-4edf-b949-9c4c0f3e85d8][SQL: SELECT aspnetuser0_.[UserId] as column1_12_0_, aspnetuser0_.[UserName] as column2_12_0_, aspnetuser0_.[LoweredUserName] as column3_12_0_, aspnetuser0_.[MobileAlias] as column4_12_0_, aspnetuser0_.[IsAnonymous] as column5_12_0_, aspnetuser0_.[LastActivityDate] as column6_12_0_, aspnetuser0_.[ApplicationId] as column7_12_0_ FROM [dbo].[aspnet_Users] aspnetuser0_ WHERE aspnetuser0_.[UserId]=?] ---> System.ObjectDisposedException: Session is closed!
Object name: 'ISession'.
```

Comment: Is it possible that one of the objects referenced by the User object is being loaded lazily? For example the User references a Locale/Address object that wasn't fetched eagerly. Also what type of session management model are you using (i.e session per request etc...)?

Comment: @Saret: I am using a codesmith template 1.7 template which is per request the session is created.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's happening because User is being lazy loaded and you're likely seeing a situation where the session is being closed before the User object is loaded. Then when the Grid accesses the User reference you get this exception. Make sure you're following the [Unit of Work pattern](http://nhforge.org/wikis/patternsandpractices/nhibernate-and-the-unit-of-work-pattern.aspx).

Also you may want to use a Model class to bind to your grid, rather than the entity directly. That way you control what kind of access is done and you avoid having unexpected changes to your entities/database.

Comment: @Yads: that is what I am seeing that it is being lazy loaded. My puzzle is I have set my icriteria to have the fetchMode.Eager on the user Entity. Do I have to flush my call to eager load it? Also +1 for your answer

Comment: @odez213, FetchModel.Eager fetches the User entity via an outer join. Are you able to see what the SQL that is generated is? Is there potentially a lazy loaded reference on the User object that is being accessed?

Comment: @Yads the thing is the exception only occurs if I try to click on the paging on the telerik grid really quickly. First initialization and moderate time of click on the paging is fine. The telerik grid is using Ajax. This issue is occuring in production and I am able to replicate the issue in dev. I am beginning to think this is related to telerik grid ajax call. I will post some code and exception msg later on.

Comment: @odez, yes the code would be interesting to see. Telerik makes post requests to the action you specify whenever you click page. You should also post the code that is managing your session as I suspect there may be a problem there.

Comment: @Yads: I tried using createAlias in the criteria and set fetchMode to eager when loading the Agents entity and still get the same issue. It works when I make a work around on my List() where I call sale.AspnetUser3.Agents3[0].Id to make sure it is loading up.

Comment: @odez213 can you show the code in which you tried to set CreateAlias and the Fetch Model? Also can you post what `SaleManager.Session.GetISession()` looks like? As I'm almost positive you're not managing your sessions correctly?

Comment: @Vadim, your answer is very useful, as Unit of Work pattern link does not work, will be good if you can add a live link.